# JRemove default selection in JButton

Tags: java, swing

[image: Screenshot]

Hi ,
I am creating a box which has few buttons in it. When I am executing it a weired recatangualr box is coming which denotes it's default selection. I want to remove it.Can some one please help me.
Below is the snapshot of my code:

```
    JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
     buttons.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue()); 
buttons.add(NCDEX);  
  buttons.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue()); buttons.add(MCX);
```

Attached screenshot for reference.I want to remvoe the recatngular box surrounding the button named NCDEX

Comment: I dnt think i understand yur question...what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Can you a screenshot of what you describe?

Comment: maybe meant Rectangle around JButtons text

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the rectangle is present when the button has focus.  One possible solution is to call setFocusable(false) on all JButtons that you don't want to have this occur on.

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels JButton#setFocusPainted(); because if is there more than one JComponents, then next gained that...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [JButton.setDefaultCapable()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html#setDefaultCapable%28boolean%29)